Can I make a dj-rest-auth login screen that uses a different database for login details?
I want to make a login screen for my Django Rest framework. I want to create a login page that's based on my database and not the default credentials of dj-rest-auth. Is it possible to do? Or should I use something else?
I looked for solutions to this and only found ways to customize my the login details with the default django auth database.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
